# Faced an error: excess elements in char array initializer during print out of array of strings

Tags: arrays, c, string

I've tryed to print out some array of strings but faced error: excess elements in char array initializer
Please make a hint what's worng with this code?

Step 1 change '' with "" nothing changed, the same error.
Step 2 change maschar to *maschar, it helped, thaks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char maschar[] = {'char', 'mas', 'got'};
    int lenchar = sizeof(maschar) / sizeof(*maschar);

    for (int i = 0; i< lenchar; i++)
        printf("%s\n", *(maschar+i));

    return 0;
```

Comment: .. and `char *maschar[] = ...`

Comment: *what's worng with this code?* You should enable all warnings in your compiler. For GCC use `-Wall -Werror -pedantic`. You should get some warnings about using multibyte character literals and passing wrong parameter types to `printf`.

Comment: @Gerhardh i'm using Codeblocks, should i put this line(-Wall -Werror -pedantic) in Settings->Debugger->Default-> Arguments?

Comment: I am not sure where to put it in CodeBlocks. You need to set it as compiler options. Not for debugger and not as arguments for your program.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Step 1 change '' with "" nothing changed, the same error.
Step 2 change maschar to *maschar, it helped, thaks.

```
char *maschar[] = {"char", "mas", "got"};
int lenchar = sizeof(maschar) / sizeof(*maschar);

for (int i = 0; i< lenchar; i++)
    printf("%s\n", *(maschar+i));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).